# Does Java 8 lack a Stream.concat working on a varags of streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Currently we have the following `Stream.concat` in Java 8:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> concat(Stream<? extends T> a, Stream<? extends T> b);
```

I am surprised as to why there is no version taking a varargs of `Stream<? extends T>`?

Currently I have code written like:

```
Stream<Integer> resultStream = Stream.concat(stream1, Stream.concat(stream2, Stream.of(element)))
        .filter(x -> x != 0)
        .filter(x -> x != 1)
        .filter(x -> x != 2);
```

If a varargs of this signature were available:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> concat(Stream<? extends T>... streams);
```

Then I could write it much more clearly as:

```
Stream<Integer> resultStream = Stream.concat(
                stream1,
                stream2,
                Stream.of(element)
        )
        .filter(x -> x != 0)
        .filter(x -> x != 1)
        .filter(x -> x != 2);
```

Without all kinds of nested `Stream.concat` calls.

Or are there other reasons why it is not provided?
I cannot think of such reasons, as we end up doing the job of a varargs call anyway now.

Comment: You might want to go through this thread -> http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-July/010647.html

Answer (score 66):

Just `flatMap` it:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Stream<String> stream1 = /*some stream*/
    final Stream<String> stream2 = /*some stream*/
    final Stream<String> stream3 = /*some stream*/
    final Stream<String> stream4 = /*some stream*/
    final Stream<String> stream5 = /*some stream*/

    final Stream<String> stream = Stream.of(stream1, stream2, stream3, stream4, stream5).flatMap(Function.identity());
}
```

In your example:

```
Stream<Integer> resultStream = Stream.of(stream1, stream2, Stream.of(element))
        .flatMap(identity())
        .filter(x -> x != 0)
        .filter(x -> x != 1)
        .filter(x -> x != 2);
```

Comment: Note: this solution won't shortcut infinite streams! See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48192709/907576

Comment: Or the [answer by assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22743697/2071828) which I think is clearer.

Comment: well, i was confused exactly by that answer, that's why i created that test

Answer (score 47):

Gleaned from [a message in the thread linked by @RohitJain](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-July/010662.html):

```
Stream.of(s1, s2, s3, ...)
  /* .parallel() if you want*/
  .reduce(Stream::concat)
  .orElseGet(Stream::empty);
```

Comment: +1. The post indicates that the `flatMap` solution will not work if one of the streams is infinite.

Comment: I could find myself in the `flatMap` version with the verbosity, however this version seems much more verbose (you need to know what is going on), it will work and is better than manually concatting 10 streams, sure, but I do not see why the functionality is not there by default.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I think you misread the post. It says `the latter will fail if s1 is infinite even for ops like findFirst` where `latter` refers to this solution. It seems like the `flatMap` version is actually the safe approach.

Comment: this `reduce` solution processes infinite streams correctly, opposite `flatMap` one. See `flatMap` vs `reduce` comparison: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48192709/907576

Answer (score 14):

In Google Guava v21.0+ there is:

`com.google.common.collect.Streams#concat` method

Answer (score 2):

SO, aggregating answers [of.flatMap()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22743508/907576) vs [of.reduce().orElseGet()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22743697/907576) : `of.flatMap` can't process infinite streams, when `of.reduce()` - can. See the test example below:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class StreamConcatTest {

@Rule
public Timeout globalTimeout = Timeout.seconds(3);

private static final Random randomSupplier = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

private Stream<Stream<Integer>> mergedStream;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Stream<Integer> infinite = Stream.concat(
            Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
            Stream.generate(randomSupplier::nextInt)
    );

    Stream<Integer> finite1 = Stream.of(100, 101, 102, 103);
    Stream<Integer> finite2 = Stream.of(222, 333, 444, 555);

    mergedStream = Stream.of(infinite, finite1, finite2);
}

@Test
public void of_flatMap_FAILS_BY_TIMEOUT() throws Exception {
    Stream<Integer> streamToTest = mergedStream
            .flatMap(i -> i);

    assertThat(streamToTest
                    .skip(3)
                    .findFirst() // this should break infinite stream, but can't
                    .orElse(-1),
            is(4));
}

@Test
public void of_reduce_SUCCESS() throws Exception {
    Stream<Integer> streamToTest = mergedStream
            .reduce(Stream::concat)
            .orElseGet(Stream::empty);

    assertThat(streamToTest
                    .skip(3)
                    .findFirst() // this really breaks infinite stream
                    .orElse(-1),
            is(4));
}
}
```

Comment: The issue with `Stream.concat()` on the other hand is that it can lead to bad performance or `StackOverflowError`s when processing large quantities of streams. This is also mentioned as an implementation note in the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-). So basically, the solution really depends on the amount of streams you're trying to concatenate and if any of the streams is infinite.

Comment: I'm confused, both tests works in my version of java: Java 11. Maybe It have been fixed? I have no timeout, so I can't really see the differences of both methods.